# Каков уровень востребованности ресурсов для каждого layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout

В процессе разработки столкнулся с вопросом: сколько ресурсов требует каждый layout? (Linear, Relative, Tab, Constraint, Coordinator)

В сложных view-представлениях приложения оправдано ли использование исключительно маловесных layout?

Comment: Простого ответа нет. Всегда, конечно, тем лучше чем более простая у вас вёрстка. Однако не любую фичу можно сделать простой и за приемлемое время и деньги. Т.е. этим вопросом стоит задаваться на приложениях уровня facebook/vk/instgram. В большинстве случаев достаточно протого здравого смысла + ConstraintLayout. Он как раз призван позволять делать сложные интерфейсы максимально производительным способом.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В общем случае, при одноуровневой верстке, в порядке возрастания потребления ресурса:

FrameLayout - LinearLayout  - RelativeLayout - ConstraintLayout

Однако, при вложенности одного контейнера в другой, потребление ресурса существенно увеличивается. Так как на практике встречается очень мало таких версток, где достаточно одного простого контейнера (как Frame или Linear), то в большинстве случаев оптимальным решением будет ConstraintLayout, как контейнер, изначально задуманный, как одноуровневый и имеющий большое количество атрибутов для комфортной реализации практически любой верстки, без вложенности одного контейнера в другой. В этом его преимущество перед более простыми контейнерами, если же вложить в него другие - оно будет утрачено.

С другой стороны, если макет можно сверстать в одноуровневый FrameLayout (например, контейнер для Fragment) или LinearLayout (например, айтем списка), то это будет гораздо более оптимальное решение в плане потребления ресурсов.

TableLayout это двухуровневый LinearLayout (вертикальный, в который вложены горизонтальные)

RelativeLayout с одной стороны несколько легче ConstraintLayout, с другой стороны существенно проигрывает ему в возможностях позиционирования виджетов и, наверное, в настоящее время не сильно востребован.

такие вещи, как CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout не имеют альтернатив реализации и потребление ими ресурсов оценивается только с позиции использовать или нет, хотя особого аппетита к ресурсам за ними вроде не замечено.

Несколько тестов различных разметок: сравнение [производительности разных контейнеров](https://android.jlelse.eu/constraint-layout-performance-870e5f238100), контейнер [с вложенными контейнерами против ConstraintLayout](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html)

Так же для оценки производительности разметки вы можете использовать [инструмент Hierarchy Viewer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer). С версии студии 3 он объявлен устаревшим и в качестве замены предлагается Layout Inspector, но он не показывает время на рендеринг разметки.
Теперь запустить Hierarchy Viewver можно из Android Device Monitor, который в свою очередь можно запустить из папки

```
 .../android_sdk/tools/monitor.bat
```

PS: Сейчас google рекомендует оценивать [производительность UI через Systrace](http://android-doc.github.io/tools/debugging/systrace.html), однако результаты ее не так просты и наглядны, как у Hierarchy Viewr